# Getting around Eigen static assertions

Tags: c++, eigen

I have some code that will run in either 2 or 3 dimensions. This is set at compile time with a macro. However, the following causes problems with Eigen:

```
// Assume two vectors exist a and b
if (dimensions == 3) {
    a.cross(b);
}
```

In 2 dimensions, the cross product trips up Eigen's static assertions even though this code will never actually run.

How can I fix this? I'd like to avoid using more macros if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it directly, because a compiler should be able to generate code for all branches, whether they are actually taken at run-time or not. If you have access to a C++17 compiler and if `dimension` is `constexpr`, you can use `if constexpr`:

```
template<int dimension>
void foo()
{
    ...
    if constexpr (dimension == 3) {
        a.cross(b);
    }
    ...
}
```

If your compiler doesn't support `if constexpr`, you can use tag dispatching to mimic it.